# "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function" when trying to use jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the `slider()` function of jQuery UI, and keep getting the following error in the console:

**TypeError:** `undefined` is not a function (evaluating `jQuery('#slider').slider()`)

I've definitely linked to the jQuery UI javascript and CSS files correctly - when I view the page source, they're all there. Why am I still getting this error?

If it's of any use, I'm using Rails and also some Bootstrap stuff. Here's the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#slider').slider();     
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Here's the `<head>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../docs-assets/ico/favicon.png">
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.core.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.theme.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.accordion.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.menu.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.button.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.resizable.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.dialog.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.progressbar.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.selectable.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.slider.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.spinner.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.tabs.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.tooltip.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.base.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.all.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/bootstrap-theme.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/bootstrap-theme.min.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/bootstrap.min.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/companies.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery-ui.min.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap.min.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/companies.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-1.11.0.min.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery-ui.min.js?body=1"></script>
    <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>

    <title>New Company - OE Fort by Oxford Entrepreneurs</title>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
    <meta content="FcOEJfo8vcCzR+Dq+5zOVSvm7Npfo+R+FoXrEPpV3js=" name="csrf-token" />

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../../app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../../../app/assets/stylesheets/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../../jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../docs-assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
          <![endif]-->

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,400,600,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('#slider').slider();     
        });
    </script>
  </head>
```

Comment: Are you calling the slider before your scripts or after?

Comment: Do you have jQuery declared before jQueryUI? jQuery needs to be declared first before jQueryUI script.

Comment: refer the slider.js file after jquery.js in page.

Comment: I've added the <head> to the OP :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would surmise the error would be caused by loading this function before JQuery is loaded yet (hence why you're seeing the `undefined` error -- JQuery is undefined)

Can you detail the way you're loading the code? Can you post your `<head>` tag?

The possible causes could be:

- JQuery is not loaded
- JQueryUI is not loaded
- `$("#slider")` is not a valid element

Comment: My money is on either of the first two, or the sequence of loading is wrong as providing an invalid element to `.slider()` doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Agreed - it would be beneficial to see the `<head>` tag to validate the loading process

Comment: Added it to the OP :) Thanks

Comment: @RichPeck It seems jquery UI isn't loading - my web inspector says that the file loaded with a 304 response, but the page doesn't think jquery UI loaded

Comment: Are you manually loading JQueryUI or using the Rails manifest structure?

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to a missing line in your **application.js.coffee** file. As mentioned here: https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails you can require special modules here.

So just add the following line to your **application.js.coffee** file and it should work:

```
#= require jquery.ui.slider
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause, I've just discovered, is when you have two different versions of jquery linked.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
      "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

... (some other bundles), and then:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ajax").Include(
      "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js",
      "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));
```

E.g. in my jqueryui bundle, I had jquery-1.10.4.min.js (or rather, the latest version), but in my ajax bundle I had jquery-1.10.2.min.js. Double clicking on the error in Chrome element inspector, revealed links to code in 1.10.2. When I changed that to 1.10.4 in the ajax bundle, the jqueryui element suddenly worked (in my case it was Tabs).

What I should have done, of course, is just leave everything at jquery-{version}.js.

So in summary, a(n overlooked) version conflict is another possible cause for this error.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this will not answer this exact question but it may help others getting the same error message for the slider() function.

If you have preset the value in the slider when initialising it, you could have something like the following:

```
$('#slider').val(5).slider();
```

if you remove the value (5), you also get the “TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function”

ie.

```
$('#slider').val().slider();
```

instead you would need to insert the starting value into the input tag.

```
<input type="text" id="slider" value="5">
```

You may have this kind of setup if the slider is used in many places in your site and you want to have your js file contain the default rather than having each slider contain the same information. In my case I needed to decentralise the value and it caused the error seen here.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this, I had trouble getting selectable to work with asp.net

Turns out I wasn't properly including everything, but this gentleman made it dummy proof:
http://blog.falafel.com/three-steps-use-jquery-ui-asp-net-mvc-5/

Answer (score 0):

try this if you are facing "uncaught typeerror is not a function javascript"
It works

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // your code here
});
```